# MP4 playback issue on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, mp4

I played 320x180 resolution mp4 file (video encoded using h264 baseline profile) on iPad mini which has iOS 6.1.3 with default video player. I observed that green strip is coming at the bottom while playback (screen shot attached below).

Later I played same 320x180 mp4 file on iPad mini which has iOS 7.0.4. The video was playing fine. Same 320x180 mp4 file playing fine on MAC also.

Can I know why I am getting green strip at the bottom while playing mp4 file on iPad mini which is having iOS 6.1.3?

[image]